# Weird height with div box

Tags: html, css

One of my div is acting weird when I'm testing it in IE.

Here is the picture of it:

[image http://img10.imageshack.us/img10/1395/mmmbme.png](http://img10.imageshack.us/img10/1395/mmmbme.png)

The weird thing is that I have `height: 1px;`. I have no idea of fixing this, I've looked around for a long time for this issue.

Here is my CSS:

```
body{
    background-image: url(images/bakgrund.png);
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#main{
    margin: 0px auto;
    width: 1870px;
}

#fb{
   position: absolute;
   height: 69px;
   width: 70px;
    margin-top: 505px;
    margin-left: 790px;
}

#nyheter{
    position: absolute;
    width: 460px;
    height: 210px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-left: 500px;
}

#nyheter a{
    color: white;        
}

#nyheter a:hover{
    color: #c4c4c4;
}

h4{
    font-size: 20px;
    color: white;           
}

#nyheter p{
    margin-top: -25px;
}

h3{
    font-weight: 800;
    font-size: 20px;
}

#nyheter a:hover{
}

h2{
    color: white;
    font-family: "Bebas Neue";
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 50px;
    position: absolute;
}

#fb:hover
{

}

#twitter a{

}

#twitter{
   position: absolute;
   height: 69px;
   width: 70px;
   margin-top: 505;
   margin-left: 880px;
}

#banner {
    height: 200px;
    width: 1000px;
    margin-top: -10px;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    background-image: url(banner.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    border: thin ridge #3a3a3a;
    margin: 0px auto;
    margin-left: 450px;
}

/*
#element1{
    position: relative;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 710px;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: black;
    filter:alpha(opacity=85);
    -moz-opacity:.85;
    opacity:.85;
    z-index: 1;
} */

#content1{
    width: 1000px;
    height: 610px;
    color: white;
    text-align: left;
    font-family: Makisupa;
    z-index: 1;
    border: thin ridge #3a3a3a;
    background-color: black;
    float: left;
    margin-top: -2px;
    margin-left: 450px;
}

#content2{
    width: 1000px;
    height: 100px;
    margin-left: 450px;
    position: relative;
    color: #a8a8a8;
    z-index: 2;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: small;
    margin-top: 0.4px;
    border: thin ridge #3a3a3a;
    background-color: black;
}

#textcontent{
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    position: absolute;
}

#test:hover{
}

#test{

}

#copy{
    margin-left: 855px;
    margin-top: 60px;
    position: absolute;
}

#kodad{
    margin-left: 320px;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 70px;
    font-size: x-small;
}

a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #a8a8a8;
}

a:hover{
    color: white;
}

#textoperation{
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-left: 20px;
}

#nyhet{
    position: absolute;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #bfbfbf;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 50px; 
}

#huvudtext{
    margin-top: -10px;
}

#rubrik h3{
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 400;
}

#textinled{
    position: absolute;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #bfbfbf;
    font-size: 15px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-top: 130px;
}

#video{
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-top: 295px;
}

h2{
    color: white;
    font-family: "Bebas Neue";
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 40px;
    position: absolute;
}

#nyhettext{
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: -23px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

#huvudtext{

}

#underline{
    background-color: #3a3a3a;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 220px;
    height: 3px;
}

#mitten{
    position: absolute;
    height: 570px;
    width: 3;
    background-color: #3a3a3a;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 470px; 
}

/*
#element2{
    width: 1000px;
    height: 50px;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: -671px;
    background-color: black;
    filter:alpha(opacity=85);
    -moz-opacity:.85;
    opacity:.85;
    z-index: 1;
}
*/
h1{
    color: white;
    font-family: "Bebas Neue";
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 50px;
    position: absolute;
}

#cssmenu{
    margin-top: 170px;
}

#cssmenu ul
{
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
    list-style-type:none;
    width:auto;
    position:relative;
    display:block;
    height:30px;
    font-size:12px;
    font-weight:bold;
    background:transparent url(images/nav_bg.png) repeat-x top left;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    border-bottom:1px solid #000000;
    border-top:1px solid #000000;
}

#cssmenu li
{
    display:block;
    float:left;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

#cssmenu li a
{
    display:block;
    float:left;
    color: white;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:8px 20px 0 20px;
}

#cssmenu li a:hover
{   
    color: #c4c4c4;
    height:22px;
    background:transparent url(images/nav_bg.png) 0px -30px no-repeat;      
}


#cssmenu li.active a
{
    display:inline;
    height:22px;
    background:transparent url(images/nav_bg.png) 0px -30px no-repeat;  
    float:left;
    margin:0;
}
```

Here's my HTML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<! DOCTYPE html PUPLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml/DTD/xhtml1/-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <title> Start </title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
    <!--[if gte IE 6]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="nycss.css" />
    <![endif]-->

    <![if !IE]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
    <![endif]>
</head>
<body>


<div id="main">
    <div id="banner">
    <div id='cssmenu'>
    <ul>
    <li class='active '><a href='#'><span>Hem</span></a></li>
       <li><a href='#'><span>Information</span></a></li>
       <li><a href='#'><span>Om oss</span></a></li>
       <li><a href='#'><span>Anmäla</span></a></li>
       <li><a href='#'><span>Partners</span></a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    </div>


    <!--<div id="element1"></div> -->
    <div id="content1">
        <div id="background">
        </div>
        <div id="textoperation"><h1> Operation Pixel 19/02-13 </br>Folkets Hus i Karlshamn </h1></div>
        <div id="textinled">
            <p> Operation Pixel drivs av fem elever från JB Gymnasiet </br> i Karlshamn som ett projekt arbete. Vi som står för lanet </br> är Adam Erlandsson, Isak Risberg Jönsson, Jonatan Tjärnberg, </br>Victor Johansson och Lucas Mattsson.</p>
            <p> Lanet kostar 200 kr och vara mellan 2013.02.19-2013-02.21. </br> Du kan även förhandsboka och betala 150 kr istället.</br> Klicka på <a href="#"> Anmäla </a> för att boka din plats. </p>
        </div>
        <div id="video">
            <iframe width="410" height="280" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/qP40Liau6z4" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
        <div id="mitten"></div>
        <div id="nyheter">
            <div id="nyhettext"><h2> Nyheter </h2></div>
            <div id="underline"></div>
            <div id="nyhet">
            <h4>Hemsidan är på gång nu</h4><p>Adam Erlandsson håller just nu på att utveckla Operation Pixelshemsida. Hemsidan kommer vara klart inom 1-2 veckor.</br> Mer information kommer inom kort.</p> 
            <h4> Datum och lokal är bestämd </h4><p> Vi har nu hittat en lokal (folkets hus) och datumet är </br> satt mellan  19/02-13 21/02-13. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur </br>adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. </br></br>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate. </p>
            <h4> Projekt arbete </h4> <p>ed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem ap
            eriam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. </br></br> Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia volup
            tas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt.
            </br></br><h3><a href="#" id="nyhetlänk"> Läs alla nyheter </a></h3>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div id="fb">
            <a href="#"> <img src="images/fb.png"> </a>
        </div>
        <div id="twitter">
            <a href="#"> <img src="images/twitter.png"> </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="content2">
    <div id="textcontent">
        <div id="test"><a href="#"> Hem </a> </br></div>
        <div id="test"><a href="#"> Information </a> </br></div>
        <div id="test"><a href="#"> Om Oss </a> </br></div>
        <div id="test"><a href="#"> Anmäla </a> </br></div>
        <div id="test"><a href="#"> Partners </a></div>
    </div>
    <div id="kodad">
        <p> Code by Adam Erlandsson. Design by Adam Erlandsson & Victor Johansson </p>
    </div>
    <div id="copy">
        <p> © 2012 Operation Pixel </p>
    </div>

</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If one of the provided answers fixed your problem, please mark it as the answer (click the checkmark) so that others with similar issues will know which answer to try first.

Answer (score 1):

To be on the safe side, write a comment into the `div` and set its font-size and line-height also. In general, all visual styles should be expressed by stylesheets, not by HTML tags. Maybe you better add a CSS border.

```
#nyhettext h2 {
    border-bottom: 3px solid #3a3a3a;
}
```

Anyway, the following should work with your current approach.

### HTML

```
<div id="underline"><!-- --></div>
```

### CSS

```
#underline{
    background-color: #3a3a3a;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    /* position: absolute; */
    width: 220px;
    height: 3px;
    font-size: 1px;
    line-height: 1px;
}
```

One more thing: Do all these elements need to have an `id`? There should never be more than one element with the same id (see `<div id="test">`). Consider using `class` instead.

Comment: @AdamZackeErlandsson Feel free to select this post as the correct answer by clicking the check mark. Welcome to Stack Overflow!